# Is there a Javascript idiom where function `func` is called as `func.bind(this)`

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I have this function `func`, that is always invoked as `func.bind(this)`. For `func`, it is implicitly assumed that the `this` context of the function is always the caller's `this` context. This seems a bit repetitive and calling `func` like this can obviously lead to misuse as some users could easily forget to call `func` without binding it to `this`. I was wondering if there is a concise way to always use the `this` context of its caller.

I was thinking about using a higher-order method that forces the user to input the context of the caller. The method would look like the following:

```
function createFunc(context) {
    return function func() {
    // rather than call `this`, you use the input parameter, `context`.
    }
}
```

Comment: Both work. Using ES6's new `()=>{}` syntax for defining functions will implicitly bind `this` to the caller's `this` as well.

Comment: `will implicitly bind this to the caller's this` - that sounds not quite right

Comment: I don't think I understand your question/problem. Can you provide a concrete example? *"I was wondering if there is a concise way to always use the this context of its caller."* No. The caller would have to set `this` explicitly at call time.

Comment: @Shadow: That's not correct. Arrow functions use the value of `this` **where they are defined**, not where they are called.

Comment: Are you sure you actually mean *"`this` context of its **caller**"*? I fail to see what this has to do with `.bind`. You usually use `.bind` to set the `this` value at *definition* time, not at *call* time.

Comment: I've seen what you're describing and will tell you that it is not safe - you can never assume that your function will always be called with `.bind()` and a `this` context. Modern JS linters will warn you about it. That's because if the function is accidentally called normally and you rely on `this` in the function body, the `this` will refer to the global scope which is usually very bad.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if there is a concise way to always use the `this` context of its caller.

You basically seem to be asking for dynamic scope. The way how `this` gets its value is dynamic, however it is *explicit* most of the time. You seem to want a function that implicitly takes the `this` value of its calling scope.

That's not possible in JavaScript. The caller has to explicitly set the `this` value via `f.call(this)` or `f.apply(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which expects a function, an object to set context to `this`, and N arguments using rest parameter and `Reflect.apply()` to set `this` at function call

```js
// default `this` object
const o = {
  n: 10
};
// `func` : function to pass as first parameter to `fn`
// `THIS` : object to set to `this` within `fn`, if `undefined` use `o`
// `args` : N arguments to `func`
const fn = function fn(func, THIS = o, ...args) {
  return Reflect.apply(func, THIS, args)
}

let res = fn(
            function func(...params) {
              // do stuff
              return params.map(n => this.n * n * Math.PI)
            }
            , void 0
            , 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
          );

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
```